# UseItBetter for Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have big Flex application and want to add analitics gather to it. I try to use this: http://useitbetter.com/ but it seems that it don't work with Flex

Maybe you know something like this that will work with Flex?

Thanks
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally used [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingSetupFlex.html) in the past to do this.  It has worked out pretty darn well :)